# Authentication with SignInManager on .NetCore API while doing JWT authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using with social media account for authentication in my application. The frontend is written with React and the API is written in C#/Asp.Net Core. I am using JWT to authenticate and authorize users' requests between the frontend and the backend.

My question comes in relation to signing in users after supplying their 3rd party credentials and receiving the access token from the 3rd party platform.

In ASP.NET Core MVC there is provision for signinManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() which handles getting information about the user from the 3rd party.

It also signs in the user after a successful verification of the information supplied.

I saw that flow in the following url [Demonstrating 3rd party authentication in ASP.Net Core application](https://code-maze.com/external-identity-provider-aspnet-core-identity/) and here is part of the code I found there.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
{

//The line below 
 var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

if (info == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
}
var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
if(signInResult.Succeeded)
{
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
if(signInResult.IsLockedOut)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(ForgotPassword));
}
else
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewData["Provider"] = info.LoginProvider;
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginModel { Email = email });
}
}
```

My question therefore is, that was a case of an MVC application.

1. Is there a way to use **signinManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()**  method in a case of API
2. Is there actually a need to sign in the user using signinManager if I am using token based authentication like JWT for my API service?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use some third-party identity provider to protect your web api, there is no need to do these things. You could just add the identity property in asp.net core web api and then the client will go to the third-party identity provider to acquire the token and use that token to this web api. More details, you could refer to this, [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview).

Comment: @BrandoZhang thank you. But I am not talking of Azure deployment here. Does your suggestion apply to non-azure platforms?

Comment: Yes, this is a normal authentication process like Identity server and other identity provider will also use the same things. You should search about or contract your third-party platform to ask them support this feature or not.